# Making A WinForm Change Background Color While Still Useable

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, background-color

I need to make a WinForm of mine flash to alert the user, and I want to accomplish this by changing the background color from the default to red, and back again every second for 5 seconds.  During this 5 seconds, I want to be able to use the form, which makes me think that I should put the flashing code in a different thread, BUT, I believe I will encounter problems because the flashing code will try to modify the form, which was created on a different thread.

What is the best way to accomplish my goal of creating a flashing WinForm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: What's the difference between the System.Windows.Forms.Timer and System.Timers.Timer?

Comment: @Soo: The WinForms timer uses a message loop to fire on the UI thread.  Timers.Timer uses the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a timer and change the form's background colour in the event handler?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the WinForm from another thread, you can use the .Invoke() method of the form. This method allows another thread to invoke the execution of a method in the form thread.

Se documentation for examples:
[MSDN: Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)